# .htaccess redirect when running a Proxy Script I need just certain URL's redirected to a DMCA takedown page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've run into a problem I just cant solve that is:

I have a proxy script running on FileHound.co.uk

### The htaccess file contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ /?load=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

---

I need to be able to redirect certain URL such as this:

```
filehound.co.uk/?load=/torrent/9392320/%5Ba-destiny%5D_toriko_-_135_(1280x720_hi10p_aac)_%5Bde83bd3d%5D.mkv
```

I want to prevent the link from displaying its destination instead being redirected to a page to i.e. `/DMCA/DMCA.html`

There are many links that need redirecting in a similar way.  As I say its a proxy script and so I cant remove the page or material myself.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: I should also mention that I have a dedicated server so have full access but im no expert

Answer (score 0):

If you put all the links that need to be redirected in a database then you can query that table and redirect if it exists something like this (pseudo code):

```
# if (url in db)
#     redirect /DMCA/DMCA.html
```

Don't forget to sanitize your input, don't want sql injection ;)

Comment: thanks my friend for your assistance but I do not have the skills to do this, im hoping there is an easier solution not that your suggestion doesnt sound a good its just I wouldnt know how to achieve it.

Comment: If youde be interested in undertaking the task please do quote for it.. Many thanks Nick